# Dev-C++ include file paths FLTK(Fast Light Toolkit)

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

When I compile and run programs in Bloodshed I save everything into a a folder labeled C++ in my username folder. When I downloaded FLTK, extracted it to the C++ folder, then tried to run a program using header files from FLTK, it was unable to find the files. My guess is that when the compiler looks for the header files it's only looking in the C++ folder, and the FLTK header files are embedded in folders that are inside of the C++ folder.

I googled around for a way to somehow have file paths that include looks into when it looks for the specified header file, but I couldn't find anything. Does anyone with experience using Bloodshed know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people here probably don't use DevC++, having been warned off it by people like me. DevC++ has lots of problems and is no longer being developed. You should consider
 switching to [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/), which is better in just about every way.

Comment: Alright I am using Code::Blocks now. Same question though - is there a way to create a file path or is there a place where I can store the FLTK so that it will be able to find the headers.

Comment: I extracted the FLTK to the include folder and still having issues.

Comment: I was able to find an include path option in Code::Blocks. Thanks for the advice, much better compiler.

Comment: I can't believe you would recommend Code::Blocks over VC++, Mr. Butterworth. I know Micro$oft is evil for software, but for software development they are topnotch!

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was recommending it over DevC++.

Comment: You were. I just thought everyone used VC++ (unless you are part of the "hacker" subculture, in which you would not even program in C++).

Comment: "How wrong can you be?" is I think the only appropriate response. Do you think the world's major infrastructure systems run on Windows (against which I have nothing, I'm using it to type this)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed FLTK properly, you should now have a program called "fltk-config". That program needs to be in your PATH. You need to edit your project's settings so that the output of "fltk-config --cflags" is added to your list of compiler flags and so that the output of "fltk-config --ldflags" is added to your list of linker flags.

Comment: I actually was able to set a path (it was reading the header files), but then for some reason I was getting function errors in cmath. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216878/cmath-functions-generating-compiler-error) for more info

Comment: Also all I did was download it an extract it to my C++ folder. I never saw an fltk-config program.